# get all subarray which have sum 0 in javascript?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, data-structures

I am trying to get all subarray which have sum 0 in javascript ? I am able to do that in `O(n^2)` like this

```
function getSubArray(input){

    let result =[]
    sum= 0
    let a = [];
    for(var i =0;i<input.length;i++){
        a=[];
        sum =0 ;
        for (let j = i; j < input.length; j++) {
            a.push(input[j])
            sum+=input[j];
            if(sum ===0){
                result.push(a);
            }
        }

    }

    return result

}
```

when I call above function `console.log(getSubArray([1, 2, -3, 0, 4, -5, 2, -1]))` it is printed in all subarray but in `O(n^2)`.

I tried to optimism  this in `O(n)` using  map

```
function getSubArray1(input) {

    let sum = 0,
    map = {0:[-1]};

    for (let i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
        sum += input[i];

        if (!map[sum]) {
            map[sum] = [i];
        }else {
            map[sum].push(i)

            let val = map[sum];
            for (let j = 0; j < val.length; j++) {
                console.log(val[j])
            }
        }
    }

}
```

above function not working not giving all subarray? is there any way to do this?

I take the reference from here
https://www.techiedelight.com/find-sub-array-with-0-sum/

Comment: In worst case (all elements `0`) we will have `n^2` sub-arrays of `0` sum anyway so we can't print them faster than `O(n^2)`, we can count them in `O(n)` though

Comment: I tried adding an answer under the misunderstanding that a subarray was the start the end. Reread your first answer and realized it was any contiguous segment of the array, which definitely means Photon is correct above. Worst-case, you can't get better than n^2.

Answer (score 0):

That site has an article titled [*"Find subarrays with given sum in an array"*](https://www.techiedelight.com/find-subarrays-given-sum-array/). It has C++, Java, and Python implementations.

I just ported the Java (and a bit of Python) code to JavaScript.

```js
const main = () => {
  const input = [4, 2, -3, -1, 0, 4], target = 0;

  console.log(subarraySum(input, target));
  console.log(subarraySumMap(input, target));
};

const subarraySum = (nums, k) => {
  const results = [];
  for (let start = 0; start < nums.length; start++) {
    let sum = 0;
    for (let end = start; end <= nums.length; end++) {
      sum += nums[end];
      if (sum === k) {
        results.push(nums.slice(start, end + 1));
      }
    }
  }
  return results;
}

const subarraySumMap = (nums, k) => {
  const insert = (hashMap, key, value) => 
    hashMap.set(key, (hashMap.get(key) || []).concat(value));
  const results = [], hashMap = new Map();
  let sum = 0;
  insert(hashMap, 0, -1);
  for (let index = 0; index < nums.length; index++) {
    sum += nums[index];
    if (hashMap.has(sum - k)) {
      let list = hashMap.get(sum - k);
      list.forEach(value => {
        results.push(nums.slice(value + 1, index + 1));
      });
    }
    insert(hashMap, sum, index);
  }
  return results;
}

main();
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```

```html
<!-- References: -->
<!-- https://leetcode.com/problems/subarray-sum-equals-k/solution/ -->
<!-- https://www.techiedelight.com/find-subarrays-given-sum-array/ -->

<!-- ∀ x ⊆ ∑ { 4, 2, -3, -1, 0, 4 } = 0 -->
```